# Passing form params through iframe with javascript safe?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, security, forms, iframe

**Background:** I have written a bookmarklet (JavaScript) that appends an iframe to the current page you are viewing. This iframe's src attribute is pointing to a form back on my (rails) application. I need to pass a key into the form (from the bookmarklet) by either modifying one of the values of the input fields or by passing the value as a parameter at the end of the url calling the form action.

I don't really see a way how to do the former, and the latter seems like a security catastrophe waiting to happen. I was wondering what the best practice would be here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appending a query string parameter to the URL seems reasonable, but you're correct - there are security implications. The value will appear in the user's browsing history and it'll be visible over unencrypted HTTP (but not HTTPS).

There's another Javascript-based way to do this that's not yet widely supported, but is worth considering - `window.postMessage`. It allows pages at designated domains to send and receive messages using a familiar event-based model. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Will the string parameter still be visible if the domain hosting the form is HTTPS?

Comment: Not over the network. I'm not sure if it would appear in the browser history or not.

Comment: From what I can make out of this system, it essentially allows you to trigger an event in the other frame, which can be used to send and receive messages. Heres some good news: It's fully-supported in Internet Explorer 9. The bad news is I tried it in Firefox 4 Beta 6 an it didn't work at all >_>

Comment: Odd. I have it working in Firefox 3.6. Perhaps the browsers still use different event models; that's been the case historically.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds fairly similar to the AJAX framework I made using iFrames. The easiest way is to have your bookmarklet build up a query string and put that on the iFrame's src. If you need to change anything, you should be able to set the iFrame's src to "#param=value" and have the page in the iFrame register the onhashchange event to deal with it (this would be how you could go about the former)
So your code could either be:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = "http://example.com/mypage?param1=value1&param2=value2";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

and/or:

```
iframe.src = "#param1=value1";
// This in the iframe:
document.onhashchange = function() {
    // parse location.hash and process form
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks. This is the approach I was planning to take, yet my question was really getting at how secure it is to be passing something like a key with this approach - not necessarily how to do it.

Comment: If you're using JavaScript, it's not gonna be secure :p But usually that shouldn't be a problem because you should have data sanitising on the server that processes the form.

Answer (score 0):

A number of schemes pass secrets in the fragment portion of the URL and then, as then, early in the page load, store it and set the fragment to blank.  I think [webkeys](http://waterken.sourceforge.net/web-key/) do this.

On the webkeys page, see specifically

> Putting the unguessable permission key in the fragment segment produces an https URL that looks like: https://www.example.com/app/#mhbqcmmva5ja3.